# Using MAX aggregate in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have these two tables "Orders" and "Employees"

```
Orders Table

OrderID   EmployeeID
1             1
2             1
3             2
4             7
5             2
.             .
.             .
.             .

Employee Table

EmployeeID   Firstname
1               Matin
2               Sina
3               Nima
.                .
.                .
.                .
```

I want to find the name of the employee which has more Orders.

also this is not my home work:)
I am learning Aggregate functions
also this a part of my query but I can not get that how can i find the maximum???please help me !thanks

```
SELECt FirstName FROM Employees E INNER JOIN Orders O ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID (SELECT Count(EmployeeID) EmployeeCount FROM Orders GROUP BY EmployeeID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select TOP 1 WITH TIES FirstName, Count(OrderID) 
FROM Employees e 
INNER JOIN Orders o on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID 
GROUP BY FirstName
ORDER BY Count(OrderID) DESC
```

Should doo the trick

Comment: No I want to show just the name of the employee which has more orders !! for example consider that my above Orders table has 5 rows and my Employees table has 3 rows SO 'Sina' and 'Matin' will be shown as a result!

Comment: Take away the TOP 1. This will show each employee, and their count of 'Orders' sorted by who has the most orders

Comment: if you write "DESC" after Order by and delete the WITH TIES!! the answer will be correct!!! thanks a lot

Comment: That's what I had :) Glad you got it sorted